# Does GCC exclude code after a return #ifdef

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Say, for example, you've got the following code

```
#define CONDITION

int conditional function();
//...

int foo()
{
#ifdef CONDITION
  return conditional_function();
#endif

int value = 0;
//...many more lines

return value;
}
```

Would GCC not generate code for the lines following the `return`'d `#ifdef`? or would an `#else` be required for that code to be excluded?

Comment: Depends on optimisation? After a `return`, more code is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compiled this with gcc 4.9 `cc     test.c   -o test`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CONDITION

int test() {
  const char* hello = "hello world";
  printf("%s\n",hello);
  return 2;
}

int main()
{
#ifdef CONDITION
  const char* a_test = "hello me";
  printf("%s\n",a_test);
  return 0;
#endif

  volatile const char* hello = "hello musasabi";
  printf("%s\n",hello);

  return test();
}
```

and then tested the content of the resulting binary with `strings test | grep hello`
"hello me" and "hello world" appear, but the string "hello musasabi" is not in `test`.

Answer (score 1):

Code should be compilable, and any decent compiler optimization may remove it as unreachable code.

Comment: To both @Jarod42 and Weather Vane: So I guess the real question is which optimization level removes it.

Comment: @musasabi wouldn't *any* level of optimisation remove unreachable code? It's a no-brainer decision by the compiler.